# Problem with responsive CSS circle div containing image

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm having trouble creating 9 responsive CSS circles in a row, where each circle contains an img tag (not a background image) inside of them. The img is to be centered and resized based on the size of the parent circle div. These 9 circles are displayed in a row and contained inside of a grid container, where each circle is assigned to it's own cell. The center of these 9 (number 5) is twice the size of the other circles.

For my smaller circle containers, I'm using the following CSS:

```
border: blue 1px solid;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: 0%;
padding-top: 100%;
margin:auto;
overflow: hidden;
```

This is based on various tutorials i've found online and suggestions found in other stack overflow posts.

The img tag has the following CSS:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
```

Based on this tutorial here: https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87

The images are not displaying - I believe because of the padding in the circle containers. However I'm not sure how to change this. If I remove the padding and add height to the containers instead, they remain circles and the images show as expected however they are no longer responsive - meaning if the size of the page changes, they change into ovals.

Here is a fiddle with the components in question: https://jsfiddle.net/jth3rb6m/

Comment: Do you have a demo you can show us?

Comment: @StevenB. I've just edited with a JSFiddle

Comment: `height: 0%; padding-top: 100%;` This is not correct, there is no way to fill the image without having a defined height and the padding is incorrect, the padding is to create internal space, the correct one would be margin-top, since you want to remove the top component. Also not recommended to let the size of the circles in percentage, will distort depending on the resolution.

Comment: @AndersonMendes so how can I have the circles be responsive without using percentages? additionally, the padding is a trick to maintain the circle shape when the size of the browser is adjusted. I found this in several posts, even other stack overflow posts. You can see here for example: https://codeitdown.com/css-circles/
Do you maybe have an suggestion to add to my JSfiddle to achieve the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the images not being round is due to the image not being square.

```css
.friend-cont {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-around;
  grid-template-columns: calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(20% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px) calc(10% - 5px);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
}

.friend-pic {
  border: blue 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* height: 0%; */
  /* padding-top: 100%; */
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.friend-photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.profile-pic {
  border: blue 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* height: 0%; */
  /* padding-top: 100%; */
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="friend-cont">

  <div class="profile-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

  <div class="friend-pic">
    <img class="friend-photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is helpful. I'd like to eventually have users upload their own images to be placed in the containers, so manually resizing the image seems out of the question. Do you have any suggestions as to adjusting the dimensions of the pictures using CSS? Or perhaps cropping out whatever is outside the circle shape of the containers?

Comment: @JonathanHinds I spend quite a bit of time digging into this issue, it all boils down to the grid system. If I use fixed heights widths, I can get it to work. I would suggest using a different "css framework" and avoid using grid-template-columns: calc().